# Meteor: Restivus API call returns HTML template

Tags: rest, meteor

I must be missing something patently obvious here, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what. I have configured Restivus like this:

```
Projects = new Mongo.Collection('projects');
Skills = new Mongo.Collection('skills');
Causes = new Mongo.Collection('causes');

Meteor.startup(() => {
    let Api = new Restivus({
        apiPath: 'api/',
        auth: {
            token: 'auth.apiKey',
            user: function () {
                return {
                    userId: this.request.headers['user-id'],
                    token: this.request.headers['login-token']
                };
            }
        },
        defaultHeaders: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        onLoggedIn: function () {
            console.log(this.user.username + ' (' + this.userId + ') logged in');
        },
        onLoggedOut: function () {
            console.log(this.user.username + ' (' + this.userId + ') logged out');
        },
        prettyJson: true,
        useDefaultAuth: true,
        version: 'v1'
    });

    // Add core models
    Api.addCollection(Skills);
    Api.addCollection(Causes);
    Api.addCollection(Projects);

    Api.addRoute('custom', {
        get: function () {
            return {
                status: 'success',
                data: 'get something different'
            };
        }
    });
});
```

This is essentially copy-pasted from the documentation. The problem is that when trying to access either any of the auto-generated endpoints, or the custom endpoint `custom`, all I get is the HTML of the Meteor app itself (i.e. same as if I had navigated to the root URL of the app).

It is as if Restivus simply is not being run at all, yet a `console.log` at the end of the code block above verifies that it is at least being run. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I expected, it was something patently obvious. I am leaving this here just in case anyone else makes the same mistake.

The key is this line in the config:

`version: 'v1'`

this means that you will need to append `/v1/` to your API path, so that the call itself has the format (for example):

`mydomain.com/api/v1/myresource`